# create custom ggplot function and set limit for y axis dynamically

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, limit

I am trying to create a custom ggplot function as below and managed to do what I need by adding a fourth argument to the first function below.

The first function gives the flexibility to set the argument *limit_for_y_axis* to any value I want; however, I'd like to know how to make the fourth argument (*limit_for_y_axis*) dynamic by setting it to the max value of the *var_y*.

```
# data
dt <- data.frame(month = as.Date(c("2018-03-01", "2018-02-01", "2018-01-01")), n = c(3000,2000,1000))

# version 1 (works fine)
horizontal_bar_chart_1 <- function(data, var_x, var_y, limit_for_y_axis){
  ggplot(data, aes_q(x=substitute(var_x), y=substitute(var_y))) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    coord_flip() +
    geom_text(aes_q(label = substitute(var_y)), hjust = -.3, color = "gray35") +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),
                       limits = c(0, max(limit_for_y_axis) * 1.3)
                       )

}

# test of horizontal_bar_chart_1 
horizontal_bar_chart_1(data = dt, var_x = month, var_y = n, limit_for_y_axis = dt$n)

# version 2 (doesn't work)
horizontal_bar_chart_2 <- function(data, var_x, var_y){
  limit_for_y_axis = max(data$var_y) * 1.3
  ggplot(data, aes_q(x=substitute(var_x), y=substitute(var_y))) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    coord_flip() +
    geom_text(aes_q(label = substitute(var_y)), hjust = -.3, color = "gray35") +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),
                       limits = c(0, limit_for_y_axis)
    )

}

# test of horizontal_bar_chart_2
horizontal_bar_chart_2(data = dt, var_x = month, var_y = n)
```

The second function gives the error message below:

```
Error in if (zero_range(as.numeric(limits))) { :    
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed 
In addition: Warning messages: 
1: In max(data$var_y) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf 
2: Removed 3 rows containing missing values (position_stack).
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be limit_for_y_axis = max(var_y) * 1.3 instead of limit_for_y_axis = max(data$var_y) * 1.3

Comment: limit_for_y_axis = max(var_y) * 1.3 gives the error "Error in max(var_y) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument"

Comment: It works for me, if you change the call to horizontal_bar_chart_2(data = dt, var_x = dt$month, var_y = dt$n)

Comment: Thanks, but, you are using "dt" instead of "data" in the call. That means passing the name of data.frame manually second and third time, which is not the dynamic solution I look for. Already have a similar solution in the first function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a string variable to slice a dataframe with `$` which is what you are implicitly trying to do with `max(data$var_y)`. Instead of looking for a column with name of the string you pass to `var_y` it's looking for a column literally named "var_y"

Replace `max(data$var_y)` with `max(data[,var_y])` and it should work.

**Edit**

The way I would fix this is to make everything explicitly a string and use `aes_string` to define your ggplot aesthetic with strings. Constructions like the `var_x = month, var_y = n` in your function call are dangerous because they will change behavior if you ever create a variable called `month` or `n` and you want to use them to refer to dataframe columns. Full solution looks like this:

```
horizontal_bar_chart_2 <- function(data, var_x, var_y){
  limit_for_y_axis = max(data[,var_y]) * 1.3
  ggplot(data, aes_string(x=var_x, y=var_y)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    coord_flip() +
    geom_text(aes_string(label=var_y), hjust = -.3, color = "gray35") +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),
                       limits = c(0, limit_for_y_axis)
    )

}

# test of horizontal_bar_chart_2
horizontal_bar_chart_2(data = dt, var_x = "month", var_y = "n")
```

Comment: Tried this now; it gives the error :  Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'closure'.

Comment: Thanks for the second suggestion; but I still get an error message. Have you tested this? "Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: label"

Comment: that's just a copy/paste error. I replaced the label in the `geom_text` aesthetic with x and y. Fixed and ought to run now.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and detailed explanation!